# Переупорядочивание колонок [ bootstrap ]

Tags: bootstrap

Подскажите как сделать такой вывод колонок:

[image: сетка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
[class*=col-] {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-push-4 col-md-push-4">a2</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-pull-4 col-md-pull-4">a1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">a3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Прошу прощения Уважаемый soledar10.... я залил не ту картинку... но принцип тот же)))... поясню))... такое же решение нужно и для SM... простите если что не так...

Comment: то есть для Sm и Xs.... понимаю и каюсь = с математикой у меня плохо....